# Unable to see trajectory of AR Drone

Tags: ros, ardrone-autonomy, ardrone

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey everyone,

I'm trying to perform dead reckoning using an AR Drone. Namely, initialize the drone's location on a floorplan, then as I move the drone around in my hands, I want the drone's trajectory to be updated on Rviz.

So far I have odometry data being published to /ardrone/odometry as nav_msgs/Odometry type. When I attempt to visualize this on Rviz, however, I only get the direction the drone is facing. I would also like the moving trajectory of the drone,  but I don't know how to display this onto Rviz.

Also note that I'm not flying the drone, simply moving it around in my hands. Could this be a reason why I can't see the trajectory?

EDIT : Here's how my Rviz looks like : [http://imgur.com/a/9BJg6](https://imgur.com/a/9BJg6)

As you can see it just tells me where the drone is pointing and does not update the movement even if I move across the room.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/244449/unable-to-see-trajectory-of-ar-drone/) by [Reijin_ThunderKeg](https://answers.ros.org/users/28064/reijin_thunderkeg/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2016-09-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Part of the problem is that there's no transform from the `map` frame to the `odom` frame. How can you plot the trajectory if you don't have a way to localize yourself within the map?

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2017-03-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0